# LOAD DATA INFILE output log file to txt

Tags: mysql

I am doing data load from txt file into table, most of the loads are working.
Some load errors out.

1. I want to save the output of the load into a log file to verify later.
2. I have HTML and special characters stored in txt file and loading into table column that is been error out -ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string.

*Sample code inside the SQL file*

LOAD DATA INFILE 'folder_Load/tbl_1.txt' INTO TABLE tbl_1 FIELDS TERMINATED BY '|' ENCLOSED BY '';

*Output from CMD:*

mysql> source G:/Load_Script/MYSQL_Load_Script.sql;
Query OK, 24 rows affected, 222 warnings (0.03 sec)
Records: 24  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 222

Query OK, 879437 rows affected, 65535 warnings (1 min 23.39 sec)
Records: 879437  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 55370493

ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: 'I have performed a left knee intra-articular steroid injection u'
ERROR 1300 (HY000): Invalid utf8mb4 character string: '            <input type="text" id="txtMissed" onchange="txtMe(th'
Query OK, 427058 rows affected, 65535 warnings (1 min 15.00 sec)
Records: 427058  Deleted: 0  Skipped: 0  Warnings: 49934240

Answer (score 0):

Use the commandline tool from Windows's cmd:

```
mysql -u ... -p  <G:\Load_Script/MYSQL_Load_Script.sql  >log.txt
```

where `script.txt` is a file that contain SQL statements, including `LOAD DATA`.  and `log.txt` is where you want to write the output.  Other arguments should be added (like u and p) as needed.  Note that backslashes are needed in cmd.

Comment: Rick James, Thank you. Is it possible to add log file in the LOAD DATA INFILE of each statement?

Comment: @Raja_mssqlDBA - No.  On the other hand, run multiple `mysql` calls, one per LOAD, and redirect output to different log files.

Comment: Thank you Rick James

Comment: Getting this error: mysql> source G:/Load_Script/MYSQL_Load_Script_10.sql >G:/Load_Script/log.txt;
ERROR:
Failed to open file 'G:\Load_Script\MYSQL_Load_Script_10.sql >G:\Load_Script\log.txt', error: 22

Comment: Put quotes around the path and use forward slash:  "G:/....txt"